# PdfRenderer keep crashing in android API 25

Tags: android, pdf, pdfrenderer, pdfium

I use PdfRenderer to render PDF preview in Android API 25:

```java
var parcelFileDescriptor: ParcelFileDescriptor? = null
var pdfRenderer: PdfRenderer? = null
var firstPage: PdfRenderer.Page? = null
try {
    val file = File(filePath)
    parcelFileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(file, ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY)
    pdfRenderer = PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor) // it throw exception or crash from here
    firstPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(0)
    // Do something with firstPage
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
} finally {
    firstPage?.close()
    pdfRenderer?.close()
    parcelFileDescriptor?.close()
}
```

But in first call, it throws `java.lang.SecurityException: cannot create document. Error: 4`. From 2nd or 3rd call, it is not responding and crash in native.
I just call it from only one thread, so there is no concurrency issue. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I found trying to open a password protected pdf on Android < P causes the crash: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37052344.

What to do is checking if the pdf file is encrypted or not before opening.